# login de usuario con nodejs y mongodb retorna objeto vacío

Tags: nodejs, api, mongodb, express, auth

estoy realizando un app para realizar autenticación de usuarios con nodejs y mongodb pero estoy teniendo un problema: cuando realizo la petición POST para realizar el login del usuario, el servidor me retorna un objeto vacío a pesar de que en la base de datos exista el usuario que estoy intentando loguear. He probado varias alternativas pero no logro dar en la tecla, les agradecería si me podrían dar una mano. A continuación adjunto el fragmento de código de la función login:

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const user = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email});
        if(!user) return res.status(400).json('Wrong user or password');
        
        var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user.password, 'secret key 123');
        var originalPass = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

        if(originalPass !== req.body.password) return res.status(400).json('Wrong pass or username');
        
        res.status(200).json(user);
        
        
    }catch(error){
        res.status(500).json(error);
    }
});
```

Comment: Intenta probar la petición escrita manualmente, por ejemplo:
`findOne({email: "mi_correo@gmail.com"});` luego si hay error, está en cómo guardas en la base de datos, si no hay error significa que el string que mandas por la petición POST está mal condificado

Comment: Hola, intenté ingresar la petición manualmente pero sigo obteniendo lo mismo desde el postman, un simple {}. Qué quisiste decir con que la peticion puede estar mal condificada? Tal vez ese sea el error.

Comment: No creo, me refería a que en el navegador escribas "mi_correo@gmail.com" y la codificación por ejemplo UTF-8 cambie "mi\00correo\56gmail\01com" (por poner un ejemplo).
Si te sale vacío ingresando manualmente es porque en mongodb no tienes el dato guardado, te has equivocado de "collection" o haber puesto mal las credenciales.

Comment: Aparentemente el error está en las lineas donde uso el decrypt porque las he comentado y ahora si me responde con el usuario que estoy logueando. Intentaré usar otra librería para manejar el hash en la password a ver como me va... Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Me parece una buena idea revisar la librería y adicionalmente podrías mejorar la seguridad de tu código si comparas el password encriptando la cadena pasada en el request en lugar de tratar de decifrar la cadena almacenada en la base de datos